# branching off a branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I did something in Git that I thought would be straightforward but it ended up causing big problems for me. I'm wondering if my process is flawed.

I was working on a branch with an associated MR in GitLab. Then I decided that my current MR was done, and I created another branch off the first branch to continue working on it).

When I submitted the second branch as a second MR, I was surprised to see that the diff in GitLab contained not only the changes in the second MR, but also the commits in the first.

I figured it might go away once I merged the first MR into main. I went ahead and did that, but the diff still showed.

Then I checked out main locally and pulled it. I went into the newest branch and rebased off of main.

The problem that I ran into then was that the rebase process was a nightmare. It asked me to review a bunch of diffs where seemingly nothing was different. Also the whole notion of needing to review the changes seemed flawed to me, because these were the changes from the first branch which I had already "approved" by branching off that branch.

My question is, is there a way to branch off a branch without running into a bunch of problems like this? Or should I just avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

> I was surprised to see that the diff in GitLab contained not only the changes in the second MR, but also the commits in the first.

Of course.  The second branch was made *from* the first.  So it has the commits of the first up until the point at which it was branched.

> I figured it might go away once I merged the first MR into main.

Almost.  Then you need to merge `main` into the second branch to bring that branch up-to-date with `main`.

It's common practice to have feature branches going into the master branch over time, and a good habit to get into would be to merge the master branch into a feature branch first, compile and test the feature in that branch, and then merge that branch into the master branch.

Comment: "Almost. Then you need to merge main into the second branch to bring that branch up-to-date with main." - I was trying to do something similar with rebasing, which is where I ran into the issue of a ton of spurious conflicts. I guess next time I will try merging instead of rebasing.